# Stopwatch Java Code Always Returns 0

Tags: java

I have a code for a simple Java stopwatch, but for some reason it always gives the time as 0.
I think my variables and what not are correct... but I think it has something to do with calling the methods during the main function? Im not sure and completely lost to be honest...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stopwatch{
  private float startTime;
  private float endTime;

  public float start(){
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
  public float end(){
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
  public float elapsedTime(){
    float elapsedTime = startTime - endTime;
    System.out.println(elapsedTime);
  }
  public float getStartTime(){
    System.out.println(startTime);
  }
  public float getEndTime(){
    System.out.println(endTime);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String readString;
    Scanner scr1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press Enter to Begin the Stopwatch");
    if (scr1.hasNextLine())
      Stopwatch.start();
    System.out.println("Press Enter to Stop the Stopwatch");
    Scanner scr2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (scr2.hasNextLine())
      Stopwatch.end();
    System.out.println("Elapsed Time is: " + Stopwatch.elapsedTime());

  }
 }
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't even compile. Please provide a [mcve] which you've *actually* run. (It's also unclear why you're checking `hasNextLine`, too...) I suspect all the problems are to do with the way you're using `Scanner` (creating two instances isn't a good idea, for one thing) and basically nothing to do with the stopwatch part.

Comment: can you ask yourself why this may / may not work: ***Stopwatch.start()***... same as ***Stopwatch.end()***

Comment: also `float elapsedTime = startTime - endTime;` seems to be twisted?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Stopwatch class is not static, you need to instantiate an element of that class before being able to use its methods.

At the beginning of the `main()`, during the variables declaration, add a `Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch` and then use the methods as `s.start()`, `s.end()`, etc.

Comment: Also take a look at the elapsed time which will return a negative value. 
`endTime` will always be a bigger value than `startTime`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code doesn't even compile. If you call methods from a `static` method like `main`, the called ones have to be `static` as well. Or otherwise, create an instance of `Stopwatch` and call the methods on the created instance. Then, you have to use `long` instead of `float`. See a working version of the code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stopwatch {
    private static long startTime;
    private static long endTime;

    public static void start() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public static void end() {
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public static float elapsedTime() {
        long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(elapsedTime);
        return elapsedTime;
    }

    public static void getStartTime() {
        System.out.println(startTime);
    }

    public static void getEndTime() {
        System.out.println(endTime);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scr1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press Enter to Begin the Stopwatch");
        if (scr1.hasNextLine()) {
            Stopwatch.start();
        }
        System.out.println("Press Enter to Stop the Stopwatch");
        Scanner scr2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (scr2.hasNextLine()) {
            Stopwatch.end();
        }
        System.out.println("Elapsed Time is: " + Stopwatch.elapsedTime());

    }
}
```